# What is the difference between PWA and Angular 2/4 application?

Tags: angular

I've done experience in creating Angular 2 applications. These days Progressive Web Apps (PWA) is also getting popular.
Is PWA a separate framework like Angular or just a best practices guide?
Please explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PWA stands for Progressive Web Applications, and is more of a set of loosely related technologies and approaches that aim to provide a mobile-app like experience for web applications. It effectively has nothing to do with a framework like Angular, React or Vue.

Google has a nice explainer at  https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Answer (score 1):

Check Day 3 NG-CONF 2017 keynote of Brad Green & Rob Wormald. They talk a lot about Angular server platform (previously called Angular Universal) and Angular mobile toolkit (https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit)

https://github.com/angular-pakistan/ng-conf-2017#day-3-summary-april-7th-2017

Answer (score 0):

A PWA (Progressive Web App) is like a native app on your phone, but it’s built with web technologies like HTML5, JavaScript, Angular, and CSS3. If built right, a PWA can be indistinguishable from a native application. 
PWAs can be installed on a device like a phone, and they do not require app stores such as 'Google play store' or 'iTunes'.